# Display a MYSQL field using CAKE

Tags: mysql, cakephp

```
<div class="nhplft">
  <div class="view_item_title"><i><?= $users["First_name"]["First_name"]; ?> in MANHATTAN has (an)</i> <?= $item["Item"]["item"]; ?><br /></div>
```

that line of code is pulling the item name from the ITEMS table and the ITEM field... what can i do to display the user first_name from USERS table in the same database on this page http://whitelabel.neighborrow.com/app/items/view/2

Comment: Post some code and let us know about your model relationships.

Comment: sorry i thought i had posted the code in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you pull data in the standard CakePHP manner.

So, if your controller pulls data from the Users model:

```
$this->set( 'users', $this->User->find('first', ..other conditions..) );
```

Your view will output the first_name column from the database by doing:

```
<?php echo $users['User']['first_name']; ?>
```

If that doesn't make sense, I'd recommend you brush up on Cake (this is Cake-101).

Answer (score 1):

From your view code I think you need to [link your models together](http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together).

Answer (score -1):

" `$users["First_name"]["First_name"];` "

Is your Users table really called 'First_name' ?

Comment: Then you are making a mistake here: $users["First_name"]["First_name"];   

Not worthy of a markdown, surely?

Comment: it should probably read $user['User']['first_name'] - note the singular $user (just a vague convention if you only expect one result).

Comment: fair enough i guess it was how the question was framed... sorry... tried to upvote but says you need to edit slightly

Comment: Okay, I've edited my text to show more clearly why I asked the question.